# How can I wait for the child process to be really started

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

How can I wait for the child process running via CreateProcess function to be really started? I think about WaitForInputIdle function, but it returns earlier than the child application draws all windows.

Comment: Do you have the source code of the child process? If you do, maybe use a named event to signal between processes.

Comment: Or use a [condition variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization))

Comment: What is the reason? WaitForInputIdle is a good function, because message processing starts... If the program is started minimize dthe child Windows will never get painted. And does it make a difference? Tell us the reason...

Comment: @Roger Rowland No, i don't have the source code of the child process

Comment: What do you mean by "really started"?  Which state of the process would that represent? This is rather ambigous, because from the OS point of view the process has really started when the first instruction can be executed. From your point of view it means something very ddifferent. So what constitues a "really started" process in your context?

Comment: Why do you need to make the parent wait for the child windows to be fully drawn? What does the parent actually do with the child once it is running? You may be waiting for the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1):

On way wo solve this issue is, that you create a pipe in the parent. After the fork, the parent reads from the pipe and the child writes some data to signal that it is ready to proceed.

Comment: An Event object is enough!

Comment: Of course, either solution assumes that you have the source code for the child process and can add such a notification to it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, such information would have been usefull in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got the code to the child process then one way is to create a named event in the parent process and wait on that event. In the child process you open the event and signal it when the child process decides it has really started.

If you're going to be spawning lots of processes then you'll need a naming convention for the events so that each parent/child pair has its own event. One solution to this is to name the event with a GUID and then pass that GUID into the child process on its command line.

Comment: Just FYI, (I know you don't have source access, but ...) you don't want to use a named event (there are security problems, unique naming, etc). Create an unnamed event passing in a SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES to CreateEvent() and specify bInheritHandle=TRUE. Then when creating the child process you tell it the handle via cmdline args (think: sprintf(buf, "%p", handle);) and the child process can grab it and signal you on it. See also DuplicateHandle().